# Google maps v3: clustering with CustomOverlays

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have been searching about this for days. I have even downloaded the v3 MarkerClustererPlus by Gary Little but still couldn't figure it out. Any help will do.

Below are the customOverlays on my points.
you can see they overlay when zoomed out. I need to create clusters when they are in close range.

```
function CustomMarker(latlng, map, args) {
    this.latlng = latlng;   
    this.args = args;   
    this.setMap(map);   
}

CustomMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

CustomMarker.prototype.draw = function() {

    var _this = this;
    var div = this.div;

    if (!div) {

        div = this.div = document.createElement('div');
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');

        ul.className = 'marker-stack';

        div.className = 'custom-marker';
        div.style.position = 'absolute';
        div.style.cursor = 'pointer';


        div.appendChild(ul);

        if (typeof(_this.args.marker_id) !== 'undefined') div.dataset.marker_id =               _this.args.marker_id;
        if (typeof(_this.args.marker_category) !== 'undefined') div.dataset.marker_category =   _this.args.marker_category;
        if (typeof(_this.args.marker_title) !== 'undefined') div.dataset.marker_title =         _this.args.marker_title;
        if (typeof(_this.args.marker_position) !== 'undefined') div.dataset.marker_position =   _this.args.marker_position;

        var panes = this.getPanes();
        panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
    }

    var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng);

    if (point) {
        div.style.left = (point.x - div.offsetWidth / 2 ) + 'px';
        div.style.top = (point.y - div.offsetHeight ) - 8 + 'px';
    }
};

CustomMarker.prototype.remove = function() {
    if (this.div) {
        this.div.parentNode.removeChild(this.div);
        this.div = null;
    }   
};

CustomMarker.prototype.getPosition = function() {
    return this.latlng; 
};


for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    place = locations[i];
    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(place.latitude, place.longitude);

    var overlay = new CustomMarker(myLatLng, map, {
        marker_id: place.id,
        marker_category: place.category,
        marker_title: place.name,
        marker_position: place.latitude +','+ place.longitude
    });

    bounds.extend(myLatLng);
    markers.push(marker);
}

var cluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clusterOptions);
```

`MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clusterOptions);` doesn't work because these are not markers. they are CustomOverlays.

[image: These are custom overlays on may points]

Any further help will do.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.